# Are there any widget sets (and application frameworks) that build on jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems clear that jquery has become the standard “low level” JavaScript library.

We also have extjs and dojo that provide application frame works and widgets etc.

I was expecting an application framework and widget set that builds on the jquery foundation to have become *fashionable* by now.

Is there such a widget set and application framework?

Comment: Just as an FYI, "JScript" is the name for Microsoft's implementation of ECMAScript in Windows Script Host and all Internet Explorer versions up to and including 8.  "JavaScript" is the name used by all other browsers and Internet Explorer 9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) has a host of widgets available to use, along with a powerful theming framework.  Most widgets come in the form of [plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/).

Comment: Do you build up an application with jQueryUI widgets like you do with ExtJs, or do you use them to make an existing HTML page richer?